# from string to number xslt

Tags: string, xslt, numbers

I want to make a comparison of two different date’s. To realize that, I want to transform to number.
Input example:

```
<file>
                <date>2015-11-06 09:00/>
</file>
<history>
                <date>2016-01-12 10:00/>
</history>
```

First I extract the time, from date. And put the result in a var.

```
   <xsl:for-each select="//item/metadata/document/file/date">          
            <xsl:variable name="d_log" 
                select="substring-before(., ' ')" as="xs:string"/>
```

So the value of the variable would be, for example 2015-11-06.
The next step is, that I want to transform 2015-11-06 in to 20151106.

Questions is how I can transform from a string to a number?
Or is there a easier way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: And `as="xs:string"` looks like you are using XSLT 2.0 which has a dedicated `xs:date` data type suitable for dealing with and comparing any dates so I wonder why you want to use number comparison for those date values.

Comment: I tried with xs:date, but i failed. Because i don’t no how i can extract the time, from date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
translate(substring-before(., ' '), '-', '')
```

to get the expected number.

However, your syntax suggests you are using XSLT 2.0. If so, why don't you convert the given strings to `xs:date` or `xs:dateTime` and compare them as such?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <aaa>
            <xsl:for-each select="//item/metadata/document/file/date">          
            <xsl:variable name="d_log" 
                select="translate(substring-before(., ' '), '-', '')"
                 as="xs:string"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="../../history/log/date">
                    <xsl:variable name="d_doc" select="translate(substring-before(., ' '), '-', '')" as="xs:string"/>               
                <xsl:if test="$d_doc > $d_log">
                    <bb>
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                    </bb>
                </xsl:if>         
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </aaa>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```